# Simple Python Logger

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Here is a simple Python logger I would like some general feedback on.

Features:

- Dynamically creates log folder and files wherever user runs the program
- Abillity to create multiple logs from a single program
- Names logs from time stamp to the latest second preventing name conflicts

I understand there may be far better alternatives to this but I just wanted to tinker around with this concept a bit!

Thank you!

## logger.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime
import time
import os
import sys

# get user's current directory

directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/logs'


def createNewLog():

    # ensure log folder exists

    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)

    # get timestamp for naming the log

    timeInSeconds = time.time()
    timestamp = \
        datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timeInSeconds).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            )

    logFile = directory + '/' + timestamp + '.txt'
    mostRecentLog = directory + '/mostRecentLog.txt'

    # create log file and file with the log file's name

    with open(logFile, 'w') as log:
        with open(mostRecentLog, 'w') as recentLog:
            recentLog.write(timestamp)


def findMostRecentLog():

    # ensure logger has been intiated

    try:
        with open(directory + '/mostRecentLog.txt', 'r') as logFile:
            logName = logFile.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:

        print("Must initiate logger first!")
        sys.exit(1)

    return directory + '/' + logName + '.txt'


def log(comment):
    comment = str(comment)

    # write to log file retriving most recent log from corresponding file

    with open(findMostRecentLog(), 'a') as log:
        log.write(comment + '\n')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you do not know it yet, I suggest you to use [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) to parse your code and have automatic feedbacks. In fact some of my notes come from pylint.

Styling notes:

- Constant names like var "directory" require uppercase style [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants)
- Function and variable names require snake_case style [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names)
- Functions require docstring, as well as the module itself [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings)

Inline notes

```
#NOTE: 'from datetime import datetime' allows a shorter line below
import datetime
import time
import os
import sys

# get user's current directory

# NOTE: use os.path.join for concat filesystem paths for cross compatibility (also below)
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/logs'


def createNewLog():

    # ensure log folder exists

    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        # NOTE: what if user has no permission to create files/directory in current directory? (also below)
        # HINT: give a way to choose where to store logs
        os.mkdir(directory)

    # get timestamp for naming the log

    timeInSeconds = time.time()
    # NOTE: fromtimestamp may raise an exception which is not not managed here
    timestamp = \
        datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timeInSeconds).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            )

    logFile = directory + '/' + timestamp + '.txt'
    mostRecentLog = directory + '/mostRecentLog.txt'

    # create log file and file with the log file's name

    # NOTE: redefining name 'log' (it's also a function name)
    # NOTE: this 'log' is not used. What it's that for?
    with open(logFile, 'w') as log:
        with open(mostRecentLog, 'w') as recentLog:
            recentLog.write(timestamp)


def findMostRecentLog():

    # ensure logger has been intiated

    try:
        with open(directory + '/mostRecentLog.txt', 'r') as logFile:
            logName = logFile.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Must initiate logger first!")
        # NOTE: kind of rugh, I suggest returning an error and managing at caller level
        sys.exit(1)

    return directory + '/' + logName + '.txt'


def log(comment):
    # NOTE: why forcing the type?
    comment = str(comment)

    # write to log file retriving most recent log from corresponding file

    # NOTE: this dependency will make hard testing this function alone.
    with open(findMostRecentLog(), 'a') as log:
        log.write(comment + '\n')
```

Comment: The `fromtimestamp` assignment won't raise an exception. The `log` variable is only altered in the local scope of `createNewLog`, so it's mostly harmless (except for hurting readability, perhaps).

Comment: @Coal_ could you explain better the first part? I saw from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)  that `datetime.fromtimestamp` could raise a `OverflowError`. What am I missing?
Second part, I agree it's harmless in this context, but I consider it something to avoid (for readability, for future changes, etc.) not an error.